# Build error referring to yvals.h in a cantata++ test project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2005

I am testing c++ source codes using the tool cantata++. I created a project, built it and encounter the following error message.

```
error I9282: the global scope has no "_invalid_parameter"   C:\LegacyApp\VisualStudio2005\VC\include\yvals.h    167
```

I find this error wierd, because `yvals.h` is not really a file in my source codes. What does this error message imply?

Comment: Cantata++ is proprietary software. You paid for it. Why not ask the seller for support?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that yvals.h is probably included by one of the many system header files the Microsoft compiler includes, and you are only seeing it in the error message because the Cantata++ instrumenter is finding a problem with it. My guess would be that there is some problem with the settings in either Cantata++, your Visual Studio project or a mismatch between the two meaning they are not using the same settings.

In order to help diagnose the problem it would help to know a few things about the setup you have, and the code you are building when you get the error.

As Joachim Wuttke said, I would suggest you contact the Cantata Technical Support team directly if you are still having problems with this issue. They will be able to provide you with further information to help solve the problem.